# Reading many small files from an s3 bucket

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I have a few thousand csv all of them quite small individually.

Right now I am iterating through the files with a for cycle and using pandas .read_csv(). This very slow compared to actual download speed and file sizes.

I suspect there is quite some overhead under the hood, like opening connections.

Is there any way I can make this approach more efficient?

Comment: import pandas as pd

# List of file paths
file_paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', ...]

# Create an empty list to store the DataFrames
df_list = []

# Iterate over the file paths
for file in file_paths:
  # Read the CSV file and append to the list
  df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))

# Concatenate the DataFrames into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(df_list)

Comment: Yes that is more or less what i am doing. In my view resources are wasted by opening and closing connections

Comment: @Sachin is this supposed to be an answer? Python code doesn't lend itself to a comment because whitespace matters. OP: Are you limited to using a Python Script or could you also use different AWS services?

Comment: @00__00__00 Consider using a database connection pooler like `pgbouncer` or `HikariCP` to manage connections to your database.

Comment: @maurice: Python script would be ideal, however i could also just wrap a python script around an aws-cli command

Comment: @Sachin :  they dont seem applicable to aws s3 right?

Comment: `AWS S3 (Simple Storage Service)` is not a traditional database management system, so connection pooling techniques like PgBouncer or HikariCP are not applicable to S3.

Answer (score 2):

**What you can do if you have access to more AWS services**

The main problem is that fetching thousands of little files over the internet isn't very efficient. It would be much more efficient to compact these files somehow and then process a bigger file.

You can create a table in the Glue Data Catalog the points to the location and structure of the files in S3 and the use Athena to do a `select * from table_name`. Athena will read all the tiny files and output a CSV on S3 in a location of your choice and you only pay for the amount of data you read.

**What you can do if you're limited to using a Python script**

I suspect your code is severely IO-bottlenecked, i.e. it spends most of the time waiting for responses from S3 instead of actually computing something. You can optimize this by parallelizing the reading operations from S3.

Given that you're I/O limited, I'd look into [aioboto3](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/), which allows you to use async/await in Python for AWS SDK calls. It's should be a pretty much perfect fit for this use case. It can be a bit annoying to get started with, but I've recently written a [blog post](https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/12/introduction-to-asynchronous-interactions-with-the-aws-api-in-python.html) on that subject if you're interested (Usual disclaimer: written by me, relevant to the subject).

If you want to stick to the standard library, the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and threading modules could be interesting to you. These are usually better if the bottleneck is CPU time and not I/O.

Comment: Keep in mind that using parallel transfers can increase the load on your network and the S3 service, so you should carefully consider the appropriate level of parallelism for your use case.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about S3, but especially if you're doing multiprocessing/multithreading, the pooling mechanisms should be used, because you might run into OS-limits on your system.